# fill json with data

Tags: javascript, json, string, wrapper-class

Hi everybody I am trying to do a LWC form where the user inputs some values and with them populates a json.
So for example I have the lightning-input:

```
<lightning-input type="text" label="User name" max-length="4" required name="userName" onchange={handleUserName}></lightning-input>
```

and in the js I have the onchange handler:

```
userName;
handleUserName(event){
    this.userName = event.detail.value;
}
```

And then the next function:

```
wrapperToApex;
get createWrapper(){
    wrapperToApex = {
            header: {
                unser_name: this.userName,
            },
     .....
    }
    console.log('wrapper content: '+ JSON.stringify(this.wrapperToApex));
}
```

The problem is that the console.log information does not appear.
Could anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Change `wrapperToApex = {` to `this.wrapperToApex = {`.

Comment: @PhilW I already tried it and did not work.

Comment: Are you getting any error ? Check console.

Comment: @darkshadowrule no. No error in console

Comment: From where you are calling getter?

Answer (score 1):

For a standard DOM event like `onchange`, you can just get the value from the `target`:

```
this.userName = event.target.value;
```

Comment: +1. Also needs to fix the creation/initialization of the `this.wrapperToApex`.